# Worksheet_FollowHyperlink - get the cell value in which the hyperlink is located

Tags: excel, vba

I have a value in a cell and when I double click on it it takes me to the Named Range Account_Number (which resides on another worksheet) and updates the value.

My problem is I would like to adapt my code below so it will work with the Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink) event.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

If (ActiveCell.Column = 23 And Not ActiveCell.Value = "") Then   
    [Account_Number] = ActiveCell.Value
    Application.GoTo Reference:=[Account_Number]
End If

End Sub
```

I would like to put a hyperlink for instance in cell J9 which contains the value 4111 and when I click on the hyperlink it would take me to the Named Range in the other worksheet and update the value of the Named Range to 4111.

I am uncertain how to dynamically assign the value to the Named Range. Can someone please let me know if this is possible and what the code should be?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have made a hyperlink to a named cell, the way to copy the value from hyperlink source cell to its target would be:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    ActiveCell.Value = Target.Parent.Value
End Sub
```

You might want to apply this only to hyperlinks to particular named cell, like:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
  If Target.SubAddress = "Account_Number" Then
    ActiveCell.Value = Target.Parent.Value
  End If
End Sub
```