# Adjust zoom based on resolution via FollowHyperlink event

Tags: excel, vba

My sheet has data in columns A to Z. I have hyperlinks in rows 13 to 49 that jump to specific cells in rows below. For example, the hyperlink in row 13 will jump to row 229.

The hyperlinks are fine until I do a presentation on another machine with a different resolution. Instead of jumping to row 229, it shows row 248.

I have tinkered with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11533942/adjusting-worksheet-zoom-level-based-on-screen-resolution/19439177#19439177) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29367434/adjust-worksheet-to-fit-any-screen-resolution?rq=1) but have had no success yet. Also tried this [less related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10966597/worksheet-followhyperlink-get-the-cell-value-in-which-the-hyperlink-is-located) answer to see if I can trick excel. I have also tried the below code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
r = ActiveCell.Row
Range(Cells(r, 1), Cells(r, 26)).Select
'Target.Range.Select
ActiveWindow.Zoom = True
```

Comment: You could make the links fire a function that find the data you want based on the link clicked and then do a range("A" & row).Activate

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to put A229 into the top-left corner of the visible worksheet area, then fool Excel by first going past the visible portion of the worksheet that you want and come back to it.

In A13, put a hyperlink that goes to A1229, not A229.

```
Sub setup_Hyperlinks()
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        With .Range("A13")
            .Hyperlinks.Delete
            .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Cells(1), Address:="", SubAddress:="Sheet1!A1229", _
                            ScreenTip:="Jump to row 229", TextToDisplay:="Row 229"
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Note that the actual subaddress target is `A1229`, not `A229`.

Right-click the worksheet's name tab and choose **View Code**. When the VBE opens, paste **one** of the following into the worksheet code sheet titled something like *Book1 - Sheet1 (Code)*.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells(1, 1).Row > 1000 Then  'this will depend on how you craft the method for your own purposes
        Application.Goto _
          Reference:=Target.Cells(1, 1).Offset(-1000, 0)
        '[optional] move one row down for personal aesthetics
        'ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-1
    End If
End Sub
```

... or,

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    If ActiveCell.Row > 1000 Then  'this will depend on how you craft the method for your own purposes
        Application.Goto _
          Reference:=ActiveCell.Offset(-1000, 0)
        '[optional] move one row down for personal aesthetics
        'ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-1
    End If
End Sub
```

Use one or the other but not both. The former seems to have marginally less screen 'flash' on my system.

Comment: Jeeped and @matthewD Didn't have time before presentation to work it out but thanks. Will probably come in handy for presentation next time.

Answer (score 1):

It just hit me. Check out `Windows(1).VisibleRange.Rows.count`

You can see how many rows are displayed, go down so the link target will be at the top. This should be accurate regardless of the resolution.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    Dim iActive As Integer
    Dim lBottom As Long
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    'Get the number of rows showing
    iActive = Windows(1).VisibleRange.Rows.count

    'Move to center of the active window
    lBottom = ActiveCell.Row + (iActive / 2) - 1
    ws.Range("A" & lBottom).Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: I didn't explain my problem properly but you got the idea. It takes it to the row but I don't want it at the bottom but at the top so I counted how many rows I needed to make it happen which worked fine on my computer until I went to another with a much bigger screen. Don't have access to the big screen to really test this now :/ I will revisit next time I have another presentation thanks <3

Comment: I see what you mean now and it just hit me to look at visible range.  Check out edit to answer..